# Can neither clear cache nor data of apps

Tags: applications, security, settings, internal-storage

For the past week or so I have had this peculiar problem where I cannot clear the cache or the data of any app because the Settings show that no storage space is occupied by them.
Is this due to a buggy update, incorrect settings configurations or something else?

Also in the storage analysis sections, a lot of space is marked under "Others" (~18 GB out of 64)

The device in question is a POCO M3 and is running on MIUI 12.0.7.0 (Stable)

[image: An example]

Comment: @Robert I have updated the question.

Comment: So devices have a functionality to "freeze" apps that are not used regularly. Then the apps and their data are moved to a cloud storage system. If your device has such a functionality may be this app has been frozen and is therefore not really installed and thus can not be cleared?

Comment: That caanot be the issue here as it occurs for apps that are used frequently eg. WhatsApp as seen in this screenshot.  https://ibb.co/qWF0KTG